# When creating Google Map in Android app, I am facing some errors continuously

Tags: android

I want to create Google Map in my app, I am facing given errors continuously.

```
[android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
[android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
[android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
[android_ws] Format: 5, Width: 1080, Height: 1920
```

What should I do now?

Comment: It doesn't look like an error

Answer (score 0):

It is not error at all, it is some kind of Log description. I saw it sometimes.